# URL error in ionic framework

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an android application using ionicframework and cordova.I want open url based on some conditions but its not working,here is the code.

```
if("notify".equals(message)){
//its not loading
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html/announcements");
}else{

//this works fine
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html/");
}
```

app.js

```
.state('app.announcements', {
      url: "/announcements",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/announcements.html",
          controller:'announcementCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

when the `if`condition executes it will generate the error
`net:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_asset/www/index.html/announcements)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using single page application structure in your design.so just put `/announcements` is 
not working.Suppose your menu url's is look like this

`<a href="#/appmain/announcements">` and this wil work

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/appmain/announcements
```